# Percentage Sign in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone please tell me how to do a percent sign in objective C (NSString)?  I mean, what is the format specifier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

%% just like in normal c.  In fact, all the format specifiers are the same as in sprintf.

Answer (score 9):

Try %%. You have to escape it, because it's a format specifier sign.

Comment: For more reference: [NSString Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)